# Excel: replace based on whole cell value

Tags: excel, replace, find

I would love to replace all cells that is 0 with blank. Normally I would use the Excel find & replace function (Ctrl + R):

```
Find what: 0
Replace with:
```

But it would replace all 0s in all cells, so that 60 will become 0.

Is there a way to only replace the 0s if the cell is indeed 0?

Many thanks

Comment: Make sure you look at the entire cell (`LookAt:=xlWhole`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function built into Find & Replace that will only edit a cell if the entire cell value matches your parameter.

Ex.

[ex1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwDbt.png)

1) There is my starting data where you only want to replace the cells where the value = 0

2) Open up your find and replace and select the "Find entire cells only" option. Keep in mind that I took these screenshots on a Mac. On a PC I believe you will have to hit the Option button to open a dialogue box where you can make the selection.

[ex2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23reN.png)

3) After that you can just hit Replace all and you should be good to go!

[ex3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qd7m7.png)